# Automate a process of actions on a webpage

Tags: automation, ios-ui-automation

I have a list with a lot of music bands in an Excel sheet. I want to take every band one by one and put its name in a search box on a [www.songkick.com](http://www.songkick.com) and if a band is found, a button "Track artist" should be clicked, if not, continue with a next band in a list.

What's the easiest way to do this on Mac?

Comment: You would use a `webdriver`-based tool (e.g. `selenium-webdriver`).

Answer (score 0):

As already suggested - you could utilize any of the [Selenium WebDriver](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp) bindings for the webpage part. Regarding the

> list with a lot of music bands in an Excel sheet

You will need data driven approach like shown in this [JAVA Excel tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/selenium/selenium_parameterizing_using_excel.htm). It works with Apache POI - Excel JAR's to work with the Excel data.